# How to increase and decrease music player volume when sliding finger up on screen?

Tags: android

I am new to android development and currently I'm developing simple music player app. Here question is that how to `increase` and `decrease` music player `volume` when sliding finger up on my main music player activity.

If anyone know the logic of these please help me for this.

thanks in advance...

this is my music player main Activity

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use touch event listener to detect gestures:

```
yourLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            // put your volume change logic here, for example compare previously recorded x/y position to new one and change volume 
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

You can use AudioManager to control volume:

```
audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                            yourVolume, 0);
```

Comment: It's working thanks a lot...